# Package 'demo_nodes_cpp' not found. Cannot run ros2 demo after installing ade when trying Autoware.auto tutorial on linux

Tags: linux, installation, path, ros, demo

I'm following the Autoware.auto tutorial. After installing ade, I cannot run ros2 demo talker/listener examples:

```
source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash
ros2 run demo_nodes_py listener
```

I got this error:
`Package 'demo_nodes_cpp' not found`

I was in user@ade when running the command.

Comment: Have you also built your workspace with `$ colcon build` and sourced the built workspace with `$ . install/setup.bash`?

Comment: Yes I did those steps. I even tried to ```source /opt/ros/foxy/local_setup.bash``` and  ```source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash```

Comment: Does `colcon` output something in particular? Have you tried removing all folders but `src` inside your workspace and building it again with `colcon`? If you search your workspace (in particular the folders `src` and `build`) what i in there? Inside `build` there should be a `demo_nodes_cpp` with `talker` and `listener` executables.

Comment: Look like demo_nodes_cpp was removed from Autoware.Auto. I refer to this issue on the original Autoware.Auto GitLab tutorial https://gitlab.com/ApexAI/autowareclass2020/-/issues/75   Thanks @2b-t for your help regardless :)) The problem is closed now.

Answer (score 1):

Look like demo_nodes_cpp was removed from Autoware.Auto. I refer to ApexAI issue 75: [Talker/Listener demo_nodes_cpp not found](https://gitlab.com/ApexAI/autowareclass2020/-/issues/75) on the original Autoware.Auto GitLab tutorial. The problem is closed now.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command replacing with your version of ros installed

for ros-foxy-demo-nodes-cpp :
sudo apt-get install ros-{ros-version}-demo-nodes-cpp

example:
ros-humble-demo-nodes-cpp

for ros-foxy-demo-nodes-py :
sudo apt-get install ros-{ros-version}-demo-nodes-py

example :
ros-humble-demo-nodes-py

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the *demo-nodes-cpp* and *demo-nodes-py* packages are not installed.

This can be easily fixed with:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-demo-nodes-py
sudo apt-get install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-demo-nodes-cpp

source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/local_setup.bash
```

Which will download the mentioned packages for any ros2 version as long as the environment variable *ROS_DISTRO* has been properly set (which should be by default).